# How to fix error 'WooCommerce.get(...).then is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to start work with WooCommerce API - Node.js Client, which looks very straightforward.

But when I copy a simple example from WooCommerce official website, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: WooCommerce.get(...).then is not a function
```

Here is the code:

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'https://somewebsite.com/',
  consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v1'
});

WooCommerce.get("products/1359")
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

[https://woocommerce.github.io](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-product), 
[NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api)

Answer (score 0):

Have found this at the bottom of the NPM package page:

> Every method can be used in a promified way just adding Async to the method name. Like in:

```
WooCommerce.getAsync('products').then(function(result) {
  return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
});
```

Which actually makes the code works now.

I still want to understand what I was doing wrong, I don't think that the official API documents website of WooCommerce is showing all code examples as wrong.

I guess it got to do something with `WooCommerce.get` not returning a promise, but again that is the way it's in the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [woocommerce.github.io](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) are referring to [@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api) NPM package where [docs.woocommerce.com](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/) official website refer to [WooCommerce API - Node.js Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api) NPM package.

Kinda confusing...but that solves the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem but with post method. Solved adding a function callback with response argument.

```
WooCommerce.post("orders", data,function(req,res){
    console.log(res.statusMessage);     
});
```